# map' object is not a mapping --- why does python return such an exception

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I think this rather may be an english Grammer issue, but still I like to understand why
would python say the result of map operation is not a mapping?

```
In [60]: a=[1,2,3,4]

In [61]: b=['a','b','c','d']

In [62]: {**map(a,b)}
    ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[62], line 1
----> 1 {**map(a,b)}

TypeError: 'map' object is not a mapping

In [63]:
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `map`; you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: While the result of a `map` application is in fact a mapping of a sort (it maps the items of an iterable onto the items of an iterator by using the given function), it is in a _technical_ sense an iterator. A _mapping_ in the context of this error message means _an object that behaves like a dictionary_ (or is an instance of `collections.abc.Mapping` etc.). `{**(1, 2, 3)}` will give you the error message _TypeError: 'tuple' object is not a mapping`_ - you probably wouldn't think that this is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `map` is an iterator to map a function to an interable (or many). The `**` wont work on the map object returned by `map`. Even if this would work as you think (as i understand it, you try to assign every element of `a` to the respective `b` element and then unpack key and value of the resulting `dict` just to turn it back into a `dict`?!) it would be the same as writing:

`{**{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}}`

which retruns the same as the input:

`{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}`

**To create a `dict` from two lists simply use:**

```py
# Comprehension
{key: b[i] for i, key in enumerate(a)}
# even simpler with zip
dict(zip(a, b))
```